# Acidity of butyric acid vs. thiophenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I am being asked to compare the acidities of various compounds for an assignment, but I am confused about why butyric acid is a stronger acid than thiophenol/benzenethiol.

From what I was taught, I assumed the element effect (for elements in the same group on the periodic table) would take effect. Since sulfur is larger than oxygen and has a larger electron cloud to stabilize a negative charge, it has a more stable conjugate base and thus should be the stronger acid.

However, according to PubChem, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 4.82$ for butyric acid, and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 6.62$ for thiophenol.

What contributes to increased acidity of butyric acid? And why does it overrule the element effect?

Comment: Resonance, resonance. It matters a lot! If you want to compare apples with apples, then you should look at thiophenol (6.6) and *phenol* (~10), in which case your argument works.

Comment: I'd hate to be in the lab unless there's a *very* effective hood. ;-) Then there's *selenophenol*... https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2012/05/15/things_i_wont_work_with_selenophenol

Comment: *“The biggest stinker I have run across. . .Imagine 6 skunks wrapped in rubber innertubes and the whole thing is set ablaze. That might approach the metaphysical stench of this material.”*

Comment: Butyric ac. is a real carboxylic one.

Comment: Similarly, to compare pears with pears, compare butyric acid pKa=4.82 with acetic acid pKa=4.75 or formic acid pKa=3.75. Where is the increased acidity ? Carboxyls are acidic, as its carbonyl carbon atom has partial positive charge . It polarizes the $\ce{O-H}$ bond, making its braking to ions easier, and stabilizes the formed anion by charge delocalization over the whole carboxylate group. That is all.